# Can magit truncate to 50/72 lines?

Tags: magit

A common git style rule says that commit messages should be at most 50 characters long and commit descriptions at most 72.

Can magit truncate the lines in the `COMMIT_EDITMSG` buffer in accordance with those rules? That is, truncate once the line exceeds 50 characters if it is the message line or 72 characters if it is the description line.

Comment: Magit uses `git-commit` mode for messages. Check if `git-commit-summary-max-length` goes in this direction.

Comment: Thank you! I set that variable to `50` and used `auto-fill-mode` with `fill-column` set to 72. That behavior is _not_ the one I asked for but I actually prefer it. I'm unsure whether I should leave the question open anyway.